# Quark propagator

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, propagator, large-n

I was reading about Large N QCD, and specifically, T Hooft Double line notation, when I stumbled across the quark propagator-

$$\langle \psi^a (x) \overline{\psi^b}(y) \rangle = \delta^{ab} S(x-y) $$

What I cannot understand is that $\delta^{ab}$? It seems to suggest that the propagator between quarks of different colors ($a$ and $b$ are colors) is zero. But why should that be true? Quarks of different colors do mediate forces between them, right? I am a bit new to these, so do correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Gluons are usually the mediating particle, no?

Comment: I think there's a $\delta^{ab}$ because quarks cannot change color when they propagate "freely" (because this is what a propagator represents).

Comment: Quarks of different colors mediate forces between what?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I meant that gluons do mediate force between quarks of different colors.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux yes, I guess I misinterpreted the meaning of propagator, thanks for the clarification.